# SSIS formatting Currency Output

Tags: csv, ssis

In my output CSV file I have 4 columns that are Data Type Currency. My output is a Flat File CSV file.

I would like every column in the output to be of the format `$####.##`

This is not happening. Columns in the output CSV file that actually have cents are appearing `50.79 (no $)`, columns that end in `0` are suppressing the `0 (40.8)` and columns that are zero are appearing as simply `0`.

In the CSV file that I am using for my Flat File Destination Connection Manager I have formatted the 4 columns as currency and in SSIS I have formatted the 4 columns as currency.

Can someone show me how to accomplish what I want?

Thanks

Comment: a piece of data with a $ in it is actually a `VARCHAR`. You need to convert your data to a varchar either in your source SQL or using a derived column transform. Which would you prefer?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the cents suppressed, your format should be:
`$0.00`

If you want thousand separators:
`$#,##0.00`

Comment: Where do I put my formatting string? I've looked around SSIS and don't find a Format String property or anything like that.