# How can I force SSIS to use a numeric data type when outputting to a flat file, instead of a double-precision float?

Tags: ssis

I have a very simple SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) package which executes a stored procedure and writes the resulting rows to a flat file (CSV file).  In the CSV file numeric fields must always have exactly 2 decimal places, even if the value is 0.

In the Flat File Destination the data type of the input columns is `DT_NUMERIC` with a precision of 5 and a scale of 2, which is what I want.  However, the data type of the external columns is `double-precision float [DT_R8]`.  This gives me 2 decimal places but no leading 0, if the value is 0 or between 0 and 1.

For example:

```
Value in Database    Expected Value in CSV File  Actual Value in CSV File
-----------------    --------------------------  ------------------------
0                    0.00                        .00
0.17                 0.17                        .17
```

I've tried setting the data type of the external columns to `numeric [DT_NUMERIC]`, with a precision of 5 and a scale of 2, to match the input columns.  However, when I save the package the data type reverts back to `double-precision float [DT_R8]`.

How can I force SSIS to use `numeric [DT_NUMERIC]` as the data type for the external columns in the Flat File Destination?  Alternatively, is there another way of setting the output format to the equivalent of "##0.00" when writing numeric fields to the CSV file?

By the way, I know there is a very similar existing question, [SSIS formatting Currency Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187041/ssis-formatting-currency-output).  However, that question was never answered adequately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the issue was the data type for the external column was specified in the Connection Manager.  Changing the data type in the Connection Manager from float to numeric fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would first convert the value to a decimal data type, scale 2, and then use expressions to convert it to a string value adding a leading zero and one or two trailing zeros where needed.

[image: Data Flow]